# Change resolution of different images from different folders

Tags: macos, preview, graphics, image-editing, picasa

Hej guys,

my case is like this : 
i have cover images under diffrent folders

```
 books -->book1_folder--->images_folder-->cover.jpg

 books -->book2_folder--->images_folder-->cover.jpg

 books -->book3_folder--->images_folder-->cover.jpg

 books -->book4_folder--->images_folder-->cover.jpg

 books -->book5_folder--->images_folder-->cover.jpg

 ..

 ..

 .. 

 books -->book85_folder--->images_folder-->cover.jpg
```

Now i would like to duplicate those cover.jpg image , one is original cover.jpg and another one with lower resolution with a name cover_thumb.jpg.

so finally i would like to have it like :

```
 books -->book1_folder--->images_folder-->cover.jpg, cover_thumb.jpg
```

I found few solutions with mac preview tool, but its not duplicating all images at once.

Any smart solution for this case,

Comment: Did you look in the "Folder action"

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called Folder Action.

Right click on the originating folder.

Select Folder action

Now select the Action you want (in your case Duplicate)

You can modify the script if you want to to suit your needs, but it will basically make copies of files at the moment they are added to the original folder in a newly created folder.